# How to properly upload and service an image with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, struts2, google-cloud-storage

I've been stuck on this particular problem for a few days now without any success so I think it's time to reach out.

I have a form in a jsp which is part of a Google App Engine web-app, running with Struts2. My use case is that this form should be used to upload a "Tile" to my back-end storage. The form contains text fields, checkboxes and a file field, which will be used to upload an image which represents the Tile (for context, the Tile is for use in a game).
The text/boolean fields will be objectified into a "Tile" Entity and stored in Google Datastore, which is currently functional and works as intended, and the image file will be uploaded to Google Cloud storage and persisted in a bucket. However, my problem lies in the image upload.

I've tried several approaches without success, but the closest I have come is using the Storage.Objects resource to upload a stream to the store. I currently use Spring to amalgamate the form contents into a "Tile" bean, which contains all the fields, including the image file (the file is currently stored as a com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob, which belongs to a different API, and could actually be the cause of the problem, but I can't seem to find a Storage alternative).
Upon submission, this tile object is passed to a DAO by my action, the Blob is extracted, and the Tile (without the image blob) is persisted to the Datastore. This part works fine. I then extract the bytes from the image Blob and construct an input stream around them and output this stream to Storage.

```
public void storeTileImageToStorage(Blob imageData, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData.getBytes());

        uploadStreamToStorage(fileName, "image/png", bis, bucketName);
    }


public static void uploadStreamToStorage(
            String name, String contentType, InputStream stream, String bucketName)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(contentType, stream);

        StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
                // Set the destination object name
                .setName(name).setContentType(contentType);

        // Do the insert
        Storage client = getStorageService();
        Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(
                bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);

        insertRequest.execute();
    }
```

This works in some respects, as a new Object with correct name (and file-size) is created in the bucket. However, when I try to open the image using the web client I am greeted with a small white box, rather than the actual image (see below).  Any attempts to service the image programmatically also fail

[image]

EDIT: As requested, the code I use to retrieve the image. Although I do not believe this is relevant, as the "white box" occurs when I click on the file within the cloud storage web client itself, not when I try and service the image programatically.

EDIT 2: Looking at this code again, I realise this will not work, as the .get() and cast to Blob will not work as I intend to. But regardless the servicing code is not my problem at the moment, the format of the file itself in Storage is my problem as of current.

```
public Blob retrieveTileImageFromStorage(String tileName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        StorageObject object = getObjectFromStorageBucket(bucketName, tileName);
        Blob image = (Blob)object.get(tileName);

        return image;
    }

public static StorageObject getObjectFromStorageBucket(String bucketName, String objectName)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Storage client = getStorageService();
        Storage.Objects.Get get = client.objects().get(bucketName, objectName);

        StorageObject object = get.execute();

        return object;
    }
```

I assume there will be a solution to this, and I will have made a silly mistake, as the file size is correct, implying the upload did work. I'm just having a problem viewing the file as an image.
Could anyone shed any light on the situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you serve an image?

Comment: What is the action and jsp you use to retrieve and show image ?!

Comment: I will add the code I use to retrieve the image, but the problem is occurring before retrieval, as the "white box" is shown when I click on the file within cloud storage itself, not when I try to service the image programatically.

Comment: Could you provide a link to download a copy of an example tile which would be uploaded, and the corresponding "white square" image file? As an additional question, how do you accept the tile bytes for the file upload?

Comment: I'm unable to determine from the code and information provided what could possibly be at the root of this. Is the image you posted the actual image, or  a portion of a screenshot? It's hard to help without more information, despite the fact that you've admirably provided a LOT of information.